# How to do a primary key to equal to an array of int[] in LINQ?

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

I am trying to select values where the primary ID which is an int is not equal to any ints in an array int[].

Here is my current code:

```
Where(c => !c.CountryId.Equals(model.CampaignCountryIds))
```

model.CampaignCountryIds is of type int[]?

Is there any easy way to do this? This error is stemming from that:

```
Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32][]'.
```

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 2):

Use `Contains`:

```
.Where(c => !model.CampaignCountryIds.Contains(c.CountyId))
```